# boolean operations in C using bitfields

Tags: c, data-structures, bitwise-operators, boolean

I am trying to implement boolean data type in C. Basically, I am working with sets.

The following code can be used to access each bit but I am unsure whether I can represent sets using this method.
Can somebody clarify this for me?

```
struct SET {
unsigned int b0     :1;     // bit 0 single bit
unsigned int b1     :1;     // bit 1 single bit
unsigned int b2     :1;
 unsigned int b3    :1;
 };
```

I can define two structures s1 and s2.. and I will be able to access each bit of these structures (treated as boolean strings).

I will have to perform set operations like UNION, INTERSECTION and MEMBERSHIP. Is this even possible in C?

Note: I cannot use Java, only C.

Comment: What kind of sets do you need? Do you mean bitsets where each bit represents if something is included in the set?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau thats exacyly what I mean.. my sets look like this set A={p,q,r} and set B={q,r} union,intersection,membership,complement,subset are the operations that I want to be able to perform

Comment: Are you wedded to bitfields or are you open to other implementations?

Comment: @andy256: thanks for the encouragement..but it seems like java is a friendlier language for Boolean operations..in my opinion, but my mentor and guide wants it all in C..!! I would appreciate it if, you gave me a solution

Comment: @Blrfl : I am open to any Boolean implementation in C..provided that it does not take up too much memory.. I am dealing with a variation of propositional logic..which requires me to use sets and set operations in C.

Comment: There are heaps of implementations online. Let your fingers do the Googling. Clearly you have not done the research. And from what you say, you're a student, and should be doing your work yourself.

Comment: @andy256: those "heaps of implementations" are not really applicable to my problem..and im not doing any homework around here. i am a researcher..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't have any built-in set operations, but if your sets can be represented by a bitset with fewer than 64 bits (32 in older implementations), then you can use bit-operations to simulate the set operations (using AND (`&`) for set intersection and OR (`|`) for set union).

Your structure is easy for testing membership (just see if the corresponding member is not `0`), but not that easy for operations on multiple bits. That is easier on an unsigned number. To get the best of both worlds, use a union:

```
union SET {
  struct items {
    unsigned int a: 1;
    unsigned int b: 1;
    unsigned int c: 1;
    unsigned int d: 1;
    unsigned int e: 1;
    unsigned int f: 1;
    unsigned int g: 1;
    unsigned int h: 1;
  };
  uint8_t bits; // As we only have 8 items for our set
};
```

You do the bit operations on the `bits` member, and the membership tests/sets on the `items.[abcdefgh]` members.

Comment: the problem with your approach is that, I cannot set the bit field to 0.. I get an error..!

Comment: @user59288: What error do you get? To access/modify all (or multiple) bits, you need to use the `bits` member. Through `items`, you can only work with individual bits.

Comment: the error was: cannot set the bit field to zero..

Answer (score 0):

In memory these can be accessed as flags, so you can use standard flag operations,

```
struct SET {
 unsigned int b0     :1;     // bit 0 single bit
 unsigned int b1     :1;     // bit 1 single bit
 unsigned int b2     :1;
 unsigned int b3     :1;
};

struct SETFlag {
    union {
        SET set;
        unsigned int set_as_flag;
    };
};


 /* example use */
 SETFlag a, b, c;
 /* initialize */
 c.set_as_flag = a.set_as_flag | b.set_as_flag;  /* union */
 /* c.set, now you can use set */
```

This assumes you have <= 32 members for a 4 byte int, you could ensure its value is correct,

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(((struct SETFlag *)0)->set) <=
               sizeof(((struct SETFlag *)0)->set_as_flag),
               "SETFlag.set_as_flag is too small!");
```

However all this begs the question, why not just use flags.

Comment: the problem that I have is commonly called "the state explosion problem" and because I am using a graph kind of data structure elsewhere in my program, it becomes difficult for me to keep track of so many flags..